# How to add on Click event on entire DataTemplate inside MAUI Collection View

Tags: xaml, .net-core, mvvm, maui, maui-community-toolkit

How can I add a full template click handler for each item in a MAUI CollectionView?

I have seen the documentation about [TapGestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/tap?view=net-maui-7.0) but it is not clear to me how to do it for a competitive element, for example in my case inside a HorizontalStackLayout

```
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type dtos:ItemDto}">
            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                <Image WidthRequest="75" HeightRequest="75" Source="item_default.png"></Image>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Title" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Subtitle"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>                
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

What I want is to open a detail view of each item in case of pressing on it.

Side note: I'm also using CommunityToolkit (MVVM and MAUI ones)

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: ColllectionView has a built in ability to respond to item selection?

Comment: This question has been answered way too many times. Just write [maui] item tap and click search. There are many questions you can see as example. The next issue you will hit, will be "how to bind command from the DataTemplate to the view model".

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions, your idea @Jason oriented me to the final solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment provided at the beginning from @Jason, at the end I opted for a simple approach with the events of the CollectionView:

**XAML:**

```
<CollectionView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
    SelectionMode="Single" x:Name="ItemsCollectionView"
    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding ClickCommand}" 
    SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference ItemsCollectionView}}"
```

**ViewModel**

```
[RelayCommand]
private async Task ClickAsync(PlaceDto place)
{
     //Handle logic
}
```

Thanks all for the comment and suggestions

Comment: Doesn't this have the problem of once an item is selected, it's not going to fire again?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a button on the `DataTemplate` of CollectionView, and if we click the button ,the current item will be removed from the list.

You can refer to the following code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:MauiMvvmApp="clr-namespace:MauiMvvmApp226"
             x:Class="MauiMvvmApp226.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <MauiMvvmApp:TestViewModel></MauiMvvmApp:TestViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Start">

        <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="mCollectionView">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout  >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Title" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Subtitle"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <Button Text="Remove"   Command="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteItemCommand, Source={x:Reference mCollectionView}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  Margin="10,0,10,0" WidthRequest="80" HorizontalOptions="End"/>

                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

        </CollectionView>

        </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**TestViewModel.cs**

```
public partial class TestViewModel : ObservableObject 
{

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<ItemModel> items;
   
    public TestViewModel()
    {
        PopulateObservableCollection();

    }

    public void PopulateObservableCollection()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
        try
        {
            Items.Add(new ItemModel { Name = "test1",Description= "Description 1" });
            Items.Add(new ItemModel {  Name = "test2", Description = "Description 2" });
            Items.Add(new ItemModel {  Name = "test3", Description = "Description 3" });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task DeleteItem(ItemModel obj)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Items != null && Items.Contains(obj))
            {
                Items.Remove(obj);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Alert", ex.ToString(), "Cancel");
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**ItemModel.cs**

```
public class ItemModel 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**

If you want to add a tap gesture on the item of the collectionview, you can refer to the following code:

```
    <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="mCollectionView"> 
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <HorizontalStackLayout  >
                    <HorizontalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                              Command="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteItemCommand, Source={x:Reference mCollectionView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                        </TapGestureRecognizer>

                    </HorizontalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Title" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Subtitle"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    
                    <!-- <Button Text="Remove"   Command="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteItemCommand, Source={x:Reference mCollectionView}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  Margin="10,0,10,0" WidthRequest="80" HorizontalOptions="End"/>-->

                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: Thanks @jessie-zhang-msft! The point is that initially I didn't want to be forced to have an explicit button, but rather have the whole item itself be the button as it would in a modern app.

I found a simple solution based on @Jason initial comment that I will share soon